# Perl Hash of Hashes Storing References To Within - Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref

Tags: perl, hash, strict

Alright I have a function which generates a hash tree that dumper prints out to look like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'shaders' => {
    'stock_gui.vert' => '',
    'stock_font.vert' => '',
    'stock_gui.frag' => '',
    'stock_font.frag' => ''
  },
  'textures' => {},
  'fonts' => {
    'DroidSansMono.ttf' => '',
    'small' => {
      'DroidSansMono.ttf' => ''
    }
  }
};
```

Now I am trying to dfs iterate for example the fonts sub tree:

```
push (@stack, \%{$myHash->{'fonts'}});
```

Then in a loop:

```
my $tmpHash = pop(@stack);
```

Then a dumper of $tmpHash shows:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'DroidSansMono.ttf' => '',
  'small' => {
    'DroidSansMono.ttf' => ''
  }
};
```

The problem is trying access the children of the hash reference.  I can count the keys and see the children.  The dumper output looks okay.  However trying to do something like:

```
foreach my $childKey ( keys $tmpHash ){
   my $subChildrenCount = scalar keys(%{$tmpHash->{$childKey}});
}
```

Yields the error:

```
Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use
```

I think this is because $tmpHash is a hash reference.  I likely just need to dereference it somewhere.  I've tried many things and all yields further issues.  Any help appreciated.

If I try:

```
 %{$tmpHash->{'small'}}
```

Then it works fine.

UPDATE:

- If the string contains a '.' then this error occurs.  Hard coding 'small' works.  Hard coding 'stock_gui.vert' fails unless I escape the '.'.  However the keys do not match if I escape the dot...

Comment: You should take a look at [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). Looks like you're confused about `\\` and `$hash_ref`.

Comment: By the way, `\%{pop(@stack)}` is a weird way of doing `pop(@stack)`.

Comment: My perl is rusty, I won't argue there.  Reading up on it.  Pop was weird... pop(@stack) by itself works fine.

Comment: You don't need to do constantd referencing and dereferencing via "\%{xxx}" - which is the same as simply "xxx" for you.

Comment: `%$ref` dereferences the hash, then `\ ` creates a reference to it. it's like doing `$n-1+1`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by running it yourself,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $tmpHash = {
  'DroidSansMono.ttf' => '',
  'small' => {
    'DroidSansMono.ttf' => ''
  }
};

my $subChildrenCount = scalar keys(%{$tmpHash->{'small'}});
```

the code you say gives that error does not actually give that error. I suspect you are actually doing

```
my $subChildrenCount = scalar keys(%{$tmpHash->{'DroidSansMono.ttf'}});
```

Your hash format doesn't make much sense. It mixes field names and actual data as keys.

Comment: If I use my existing code but hardcode the keys then it works.  If I do a foreach key loop and try and reference the key as a var then it gives that error.  Yes it is a weird hash format, for an odd job.  Hashes with children are directory, hashes with no children are files.  No more information is required.

Comment: See the update.  It seems to be all about the '.' in the key string.  Unfortunately if I escape the '.' with some regex then that error disappears and everything iterates fine except 'Foo\.ext' won't match the key 'Foo.ext'.

Comment: No, there' no problem with keys with periods itself. Stop blaming Perl for bugs in your code.

Comment: A common response from you...  If $myKey contains the string "foo.bar" it gives the error about not being able to use an empty string as a hash ref.  If $myKey contains "foo_bar" it works perfect.  If I escape the dot with a sed it works but keys do not match anymore.  I have "$myKey" wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Nonsense. You get that error when the $x is the empty string in $x->{$mykey}, not when $x or $mykey contains `foo.bar`.

Comment: Using dumper when the value of $myKey is: $VAR1 = 'stock_gui.vert'; The error I posted above occurs.  When dumper shows it as $VAR1 = 'small'; The code works fine.  If I change the hash to be 'stock_gui_vert' it works just fine.

Comment: What's this got to do with your question or my answer?!

Comment: Again, if you get "Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref", it's because you are doing `$x->{$y}` and `$x` contains an empty string.